# Is it possible to have a front-facing content creation form, for use of visitors, that creates draft content?

Tags: channel-entries

A client is interested in allowing visitors to leave their personal stories on the site. Ideally these would go to the content list in draft mode and then be published by staff.

Is it possible to take a content creation form for a channel, and put it in the front end, with no requirement to log in?

It's no big deal if it can't be done. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, there are a few different ways that you can do it.

The first would be to create a new channel for the users Personal Stories, with a few custom fields. Name, Story, Location or any other fields you would need. Then you can use the first party module [SafeCracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/) to allow the user to post to the newly created channel. You can pass the status parameter as a hidden field to either closed or whatever status you want. To enable a guest to publish to the channel you can use the `logged_out_member_id` parameter ([docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#allowing-guests-to-post-entries)) along with a created guest member.

The other option would to be use something like Freeform to allow the collection of submissions then use the `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag pair to show the Freeform entries on the front-end of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Allow guests to post: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#allowing-guests-to-post-entries

Then you can set a suitable status
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#status
 and specify a default status